# The image file is not generating properly in SQL server 2008 using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server-2008, file, excel, xp-cmdshell

Please help me out to resolve this issue, I tried several options but unable to get success till now, any

help would be greately apprecaited.

I am generating one image file using xp_cmdshell on SQL Server 2008, the image is not getting generated in the excel file while doing this, the same image generates properly while running the same through command prompt and on SQL Server 2003.

So based on above scenario, I think the problem is not with the code, the problem is with some setting on SQL Server 2008 related to xp_cmdshell command.

Can you please provide me some guidance to resovle this issue, let me know if you have any questions on this.

Thanks,

Shoeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the windows permissions for user, under which the sql server is run

**also**

check if using `xp_cmdshell` is not prohibited on the server level by command

```
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell'
```

**and** check that is user running this command is sysadmin **or** there is set proxy account on `##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##`

[See more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Can you explain it in a more detail.

Comment: The account has the permission to run the xp_cmdshell command and it is not a proxy account, and one more the image excel file is getting created, but the image is not showing properly, means the xp_cmdshell has the permission to run the file, problem is image is not generating properly, please provide your suggestions.